# Android Cordova app rendering slowly after Chrome 72 update

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, google-chrome, hybrid

I'm wondering if anyone else is experiencing a similar issue. I have a Cordova Android app which runs perfectly on Android devices running Chrome 71 and earlier. Since the Chrome 72 update the app finishes Ajax calls and receives data successfully. After the ajax call the jquery clone creates dynamic elements from the data. This used to take maybe 2 or 3 seconds. Since the update it make take 2 or 3 minutes.

I have installed the latest Android 9 sdks on Android Studio and updated Cordova and npm.

I'm now stuck as to where to start debugging the issue. Any ideas of help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but my app completely times out giving "E/CordovaWebViewImpl: CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR". I use the default timeout for loading index.html which is about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was related to .ajaxStart(). I removed it and things improved. I still have got to find time to work of a long term fix. Hope this helps.